# Почему не работает замена 1 000 000 000 на 1B? С заменой 1 000 000 на 1M все в порядке

Tags: javascript

```
function rounding() {

if ( x >= 1000000 ) {
    x = Math.round (x/1000000);
    x = x + ("M");
  }
  else if ( x >= 1000000000 ){
    x = Math.round (x/100000000);
    x = x + ("B");
  }
  else {

  }
}
```

Comment: Одного нуля не хватает в  x = Math.round (x/100000000); но это ситуацию не исправило.

Comment: Потому что условия нужно проверять в обратном порядке. Сначала миллиард, потом миллион.

Comment: Как же я сглупил :/ Спасибо

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ответы в ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должно работать

```
function rounding() {

    if ( x >= 1000000000 ) {
        x = Math.round (x/1000000000);
        x = x + ("B");
    }
    else if ( x >= 1000000 ){
        x = Math.round (x/1000000);
        x = x + ("M");
    }
    else {
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: уже ответили :) ладно...)

Answer (score 1):

Тогда уже так:

```js
function rounding(num) {
  var suffix = ['','k', 'M', 'B', 'T','P', 'E', 'Z','Y'];
  var suffixIndex = 0;
  while(num>1000) {
    num = Math.round(num/1000);
    suffixIndex++;
  }
  return num + suffix[suffixIndex];
}

// test
var testValues = [1,2,600,1100,2100100,3100100100,4500100100100];
for(var i = 0; i < testValues.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML += 'rounding(' + testValues[i] + ') = ' + rounding(testValues[i]) + '<br />';
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Красивое решение. Только я бы на всякий случай добавил `while(num>1000 && suffixIndex < suffix.length - 1)`, авось гигант-число попадется :)

Comment: Учитывая ограничения на int в javascript `rounding(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` получается "всего лишь" 9P, так что все, что дальше P вроде как излишне. Но подстраховка никогда не помешает.